# NSUserDefaults array not saving properly

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem i cant get my head around. I have an instance of NSUserDefaults and have stored some values in there. One of these values is an array that contains the players scores (its a game) to be used in another display. After the game is finished, I update the array with the new score and reassign it to the NSUserDefaults, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be behaving correctly and in debug when i try to print the count into he console, its always 0.

Here is the code in question:

```
// //  SAMHighScoreInputViewController.m //  Tappity // //  Created by Sam on 29/05/13. //  Copyright (c) 2013 Sam. All rights reserved. //

#import "SAMHighScoreInputViewController.h"
#import "SAMScoreObject.h"

@interface SAMHighScoreInputViewController ()

@end

@implementation SAMHighScoreInputViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.nameScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastName"], [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastScore"]];
    self.nameTextField.text = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastName"];

    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view. }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }





- (IBAction)textFieldValueChanged:(UITextField *)sender {

    self.nameScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", self.nameTextField.text, [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastScore"]];
     }

- (IBAction)submitButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {



    SAMScoreObject *score = [[SAMScoreObject alloc] init];

    score.playerName = self.nameTextField.text;
    score.score = [self.defaults integerForKey:@"lastScore"];



    NSArray *scores = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"scoresArray"];

    NSMutableArray *updatedArray = [scores mutableCopy];

    [updatedArray addObject:score];

    NSArray *updatedArrayScores = [updatedArray copy];

    [self.defaults setObject:updatedArrayScores forKey:@"scoresArray"];

    [self.defaults setObject:[self.defaults objectForKey:@"scoresArray"] forKey:@"scoresArray"];

    [self.defaults synchronize];


    NSLog(@"%@, %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastScore"], [self.defaults objectForKey:@"lastName"]);
    NSLog(@"%i", [[self.defaults objectForKey:@"scoresArray"] count]);


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     } @end
```

Comment: I don't see the error, but I suggest two improvements to your code: 1) The step where you make another copy of the array and assign it to `updatedArrayScores` is unnecessary, just pass `updatedArray` directly to `NSUserDefaults`. 2) You can entirely delete the statement `[self.defaults setObject:[self.defaults objectForKey:@"scoresArray"] forKey:@"scoresArray"];`.

Comment: How is the property for `self.defaults` setup? Are you definitely retaining it. If it is not retained then it may have been released before you send the `setObject:forKey:` and 'synchonize` methods and it will just fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize your `SAMScoreObject` into an `NSData` object of some form before you can store it in the `NSUserDefaults` store.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

The fact that you're storing an `NSArray` object isn't good enough, because the objects in that array aren't one of the supported types.

Comment: This seems the most plausible reason why things aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `scoresArray` ever created? You should probably lazily create it when you attempt to update it. For example:

```
NSArray *scores = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"scoresArray"];
if(scores == nil)
{
    scores = [NSArray array];
}
NSMutableArray *updatedArray = [scores mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Kind of already did that to an extent but this didn't fix the problem, thanks for the help thought.